# npm install from private gitlab repository - authentication failed

Tags: linux, node.js, git, npm, installation

My issue is the next.

When I try install a private repository with npm which I have authorization (npm install git+url_of_my_repo_with_https), I have the next error:

npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://dbanos@gitlab.com/umbela/apiDMLOracle.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/https-dbanos-gitlab-com-umbela-apiDMLOracle-git-e2462cad: fatal: Authentication failed for url_of_my_repo_with_https
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "git+https://dbanos@gitlab.com/umbela/apiDMLOracle.git#v1.0.9"
npm ERR! node v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.0
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/https-dbanos-gitlab-com-umbela-apiDMLOracle-git-e2462cad'...
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'url_of_my_repo_with_https'

Comment: Removed "I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot in advance."

Comment: Take a look at this utility: https://github.com/twilson63/npm-gitlab , it may help.